# Can't create a Vue project with vue/cli

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli-3, npm-scripts

I'm trying create a vuex application with Vue CLI.

However, CLI freezes while fetching metadata (`chokidar@2.1.6`):

> `/ fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule chokidar@2.1.6 checking installable status`

I am using:

- npm version : `6.10.1`
- node.js version : `10.16.0`

***Screenshoot :***

[image]

I searched about this problem, common solutions were:

1. **proxy issues**

   I tried:

   ```
   npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org"`
   ```

   but there isn't any issue
2. **cache clear**

   I also tried

   ```
   npm cache clear
   ```

   however, it's still not working

Is there any log file for vue/cli to know what is causing this problem?

How can I solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I removed Vue cli.

Now i can't install vue cli. same problem appears. hanging on `fetchMetadata`

I updated the npm registry to `http://registry.npmjs.org` instead of `https`. but it's not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**, It was a problem in network

Answer (score 2):

For me on Windows 10, once it solves the problem with `npm cache clear --force` and second time uninstalling the Node and reinstalling Node and NPM did the trick.

Comment: I've tried cleaning the cache and uninstalling Node and NPM. and I installed more than one version. Now I have node `version 12.8.1` and NPM `version 6.10.2`